# $\operatorname{Hom}(f^*F, G) = \operatorname{Hom}(F, f_*G)$

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

For topological spaces $X, Y$ and the continuous morphism $f \colon Y \to X$, 
consider the sheaf $F$ on $X$ and $G$ on $Y$. A very famous formula says that

${\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{sh}}}(f^*F,G) = {\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{sh}}}(F,f_*G) \cdots (*)$,

where ${\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathrm{sh}}$ denotes the set of all homomorphisms between sheaves.

We recall that for an open subset $U \subset Y$ we define a presheaf $P$ on $Y$ as $\Gamma(U,P) \colon= \Gamma(f(U),F)$, and that traditionally the associated sheaf $P^{\mathrm{a}}$ is denoted $f^*F$. On the other hand $f_*G$ is known to be a sheaf.

I can prove the equality

${\mathrm{Hom}_{{\mathrm{pre}}}}(P,G) = {\mathrm{Hom}_{{\mathrm{pre}}}}(F,f_*G) \cdots (**)$.

where ${\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathrm{pre}}$ denotes the set of all homomorphisms between presheaves.

### Question: Is it true that ${\mathrm{Hom}_{{\mathrm{pre}}}}(P,G) = {\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{sh}}}(P^{\mathrm{a}},G)$ holds?

Namely I think that to prove $(*)$, it suffices to prove $(**)$ of homomorphisms as presheaves and apply the equality in Question 2.

Comment: It is true for any presheaf $P$. This is called "sheafification is left adjoint to inclusion of sheaves in presheaves".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheafification#Sheafification